# OS path insert command

Tags: python

There are some problems using the PYTHONPATH env variable. Therefore I have to figure out some other option in my code to import modules from another folder. I was trying the sys.path,insert based on "TEST_INSTALL_DIR" env variable ( value=C:\test).

I want to create

```
path = os.getenv("TEST_INSTALL_DIR")#C:\test
path=  path.replace("\\", "/")
pypath= '%s/python/profile'%(path)#C:/test/python/profile
pypath= "\'%s\'" %(pypath)# 'C:/test/python/profile'
print "PYPATH:",pypath
sys.path.insert(0, pypath)
```

If set the path as below ,everything works fine. :

```
 sys.path.insert(0, 'C:/test/python/profile')
```

Am I doing anything completely wrong in my code? Any ideas would help. Thanks.

Comment: Get rid of the single quotes you are adding to the path.

Comment: I tried removing single quotes. Did not help.

Answer (score 1):

I think the comment of sberry should be correct.  Just to be sure have you tried the following?

```
path = os.getenv("TEST_INSTALL_DIR")#C:\test
path = path.replace("\\", "/")
pypath = '%s/python/profile'%(path)#C:/test/python/profile
print "PYPATH:",pypath
sys.path.insert(0, pypath)
```